# How to reverse the behavior of a thermistor?

Tags: resistors, analog, signal-processing, thermistor, troubleshooting

I have  an NTC thermistor that reduces its resistance when temperature increases, but I need a circuit where resistance increases. Without using a different thermistor (or a microcontroller), is there any way that I can reverse the behavior of the thermistor so that resistance increases with temperature? Is there a component that can do this?

Comment: how is it connected in a circuit?

Comment: I haven't built the circuit yet I'm trying to see if this is even a possibility, but it will be going to an LED

Comment: think about what happens if the thermistor is one leg of a voltage divider ... think about how the output voltage varies with temperature if the thermistor is at top, and if it's at bottom

Comment: this is an XY question ... you ask about what you think is a solution to an unspecified problem, instead of asking about the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: If the range of temperature is not too great, you could try a PTC thermistor, usually used as a solid state self-resetting fuse. This might help: https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/download/531356/728d0d379187d1dfa0831555b8c93202/pdf-general-technical-information.pdf

Comment: The opposite  of an NTC is a PTC...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... is there any way that I can reverse the behavior of the thermistor ...

You can't.

But you can "reverse" the behavior of the "circuit" you can use, as this :

[image]